# Evaluation of variants of Fourier coefficient

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose we know how to evaluate the following integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\theta)e^{in\theta}\ d\theta=g(n, x).$$
Is there a general technique to evaluate/estimate
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\theta)e^{i(h(\theta)+n\theta)}\ d\theta$$
for $h(\theta) = -2\arctan(\sin\theta/(1-\cos\theta))$ for example?